# hide samba share names

Tags: linux, samba

Just typed

```
smb://user@ip
```

in Dolphin and it showed the samba shares to me without asking for any password. Trying to enter any of the shares requires a password which provides some kind of security. But it will be interesting to also hide the shares. Would that be possible?

Perhaps I've not used the best word (hide) to describe what I would like to have. I don' want to allow access, not even to list the shares, to anyone without a password (ideally).

I would appreciate comments on the issue.

Comment: Shares with a trailing `$` in the share name will be hidden from Windows systems. Dolphin seems to follow this, as well as hiding names beginning with `.`, unless you enable showing of hidden files (`Alt-.`). This is only a cosmetic work-round, not a security solution. Nautilus always shows such names. You could experiment with permissions if you can control this on the share (eg `wx` without `r`).

Answer (score 2):

Under each share setting in smb.conf, you need to set:

browseable (S)

```
**This controls whether this share is seen in the list of available shares in a net view and in the browse list.**

Default: browseable = yes
```

Comment: Well, yes. But doing so also hides the share in Windows Explorer. In Windows Explorer I only see the shares after providing the password (in my knowledge). Is it also possible, in the Windows world, to see the shares not providing the password?

Comment: I think it's exclusive - either you hide them or you show them.  At least, that has been my experience - maybe someone else can chime in.

Comment: Windows will also enumerate shares without a password. It will, however, try to log in using your current username. If it exists server-side, a password prompt appears if the login fails.

Answer (score 2):

Samba has a `smb.conf` option that makes it do exactly what you want: To enumerate shares based on access. It’s called [`access based share enum`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#idp58042160):

> If this parameter is `yes` for a service, then the share hosted by the service will only be visible to users who have read or write access to the share during share enumeration (for example net view \sambaserver). This has parallels to access based enumeration, the main difference being that only share permissions are evaluated, and security descriptors on files contained on the share are not used in computing enumeration access rights.
>
> Default: `access based share enum = no`

This option can be set either in the `[global]` section, where it will set the default or locally in a share section, where it will override the default/global option.

There is, however, a rather **severe limitation**: To edit the share permissions ACL, you need to connect using Windows’ MMC console. You also need the `SeDiskOperatorPrivilege`, which unfortunately cannot be granted without joining Samba to an Active Directory Domain.

Share permissions are *not* the same as `valid users` and the like.

Comment: It's being said (http://forums.openmediavault.org/index.php/Thread/11607-Samba-access-based-share-enum-workaround-for-workgroups-Hide-shares-that-users-d/) that  "the option only applies to domains, and not to workgroups". I'm using workgroups, I tried it here, and didn't saw any effect.

Comment: Well, it looks like you’re right. To modify share permissions ACL (*not* the same as `valid users` etc), Samba needs to be joined to a Domain. Rather underwhelming.

Comment: I think `access based share enum` might not help or I did not understand how to use it. So I posted a specific question http://superuser.com/questions/1040863/samba-access-based-share-enum-explained-in-the-active-directory-context.